# Eliminate specific number in a data file using Python

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a large file and I want to delete all the values '24' within the data file. I have used this code but it doesn't do what I want. Suggestions please. Thanks

**This is the data file**

```
24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,24,1000,1000,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000
```

**Code**

```
content = open('txt1.txt', 'r').readlines()
cleandata = []
for line in content:
    line = {i:None for i in line.replace("\n", "").split()}
    for value in line.copy():
         if value == "24":
            line.pop(value)
    cleandata.append(" ".join(line) + "\n")

open('txt2.txt', 'w').writelines(cleandata)
```

Comment: Any specific error with this code? Or simply doesn't give the correct result?

Comment: It doesn't do any changes at all @Lorenzo Zane

Comment: `line = {...}` you create dict and it contains a unique key (i) only. You probably need list or generator  and you may filter out on creation with `(i for i in line.split(',') if i != '24')`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```py
content = open('txt1.txt', 'r').readlines()

cleandata = []
for line in content:
    line = line.replace('24','')
    cleandata.append(line)
    
open('txt2.txt', 'w').writelines(cleandata)
```

Comment: this also removes somethings which probably should not be removed, like: `Hello 124` -> `Hello 1`

Comment: @thatguyfig I tried this and it does remove the 24 values but it substitutes them by a comma ','. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex for it, to match the 24 and delete it.

```
import re

regex24 = re.compile(r"\b24,?\b")

f = open('txt1.txt', 'r')
cleans = [regex24.sub("", line) for line in f.readlines()]

open('txt2.txt', 'w').writelines(cleans)
```

Comment: There is an error f = open('BVE300_6.txt, 'r')
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @Alex8798 the code in the comment missing a quote after BVE300_6.txt, probably that's why there is a syntax error for you, I also change the regex to remove commas, because you updated the question in the meantime.

Comment: Szabo Thanks, i tried your code now, no errors but I open the file and its literally empty blank!

Comment: @Alex8798 you most probably provided the same file to write to as read from. I updated my answer to work if you want to use it on the same file name and path.